# Finding php location on MacOS Ventura

Tags: macos, php, macos-ventura

I'm using MacOS Ventura. PHP and Apache are running ok because i can access both on the browser localhost.

But how can i find out where the current PHP version is installed ? When i go to the prompt and type this :

```
which php
```

I get

```
php not found
```

Comment: In the process of getting PHP to work again. When I ran the"which php" command I get /usr/local/bin/php 
You might check that directory to see if it exists.
(NOTE: I can't remember how I installed PHP after the last major update... so might not be the same as you)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you installed it with Homebrew.

If so, you can try:

```
brew search php
```

This will tell you if it's at least installed. Depending on your Homebrew setup, the location can vary.

I just updated to the Mac OS Sonoma beta, and it broke my PHP setup. I ended up using the following command to install using Homebrew:

```
brew install php
```

When it completes installation, it will show you the path it installed PHP on your machine right in the output.

You can also now run your original command and it should show your PHP location:

```
which php
```

In my case, I was trying to fix a PHP environment error in VS Code. After doing both of those commands above, I grabbed the path from the output and put it into my VS Code settings.

I'm not sure if your use case is the same, but a few more options to try.